# drupal console Windows Git bash tar error

Tags: git, bash, drupal, drupal-8

Could not able to install Drupal 8 from Drupal Console in Windows 10 OS.
When I run the following command

```
drupal chain --file=.console\chain/quick-start.yml
```

it throw the error

```
[ERROR] Unable to execute the following command "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\tar.EXE" "--extract"
         "--file=C:\Users\KARTHI~1\AppData\Local\Temp/drupal.tar.gz" "--overwrite-dir" "--overwrite" "--gzip"
         "--directory" "C:\Users\karthikeyan/" {output: /usr/bin/tar: '--overwrite' cannot be used with
         '--overwrite-dir'
Try '/usr/bin/tar --help' or '/usr/bin/tar --usage' for more information.
}
 Drupal "8.2.6" was downloaded in directory "drupal-8.2.6"
 [ERROR] An error occurred while renaming directory as "drupal8.dev"
```

Comment: I notice the same issue raised in the project - https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/issues/2214 and https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/issues/2584

Comment: Yes, that's true but no much activity in issues part of the project. That's why I raised here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to have been fixed in 1.0.0-rc13 try using this version.
[Commit](https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/pull/3053)

Try to update the vendor package - `php composer.phar update` to update a specific vendor use - `php composer.phar update vendor/packagename`